# How to extract top 7 value from aggregate in r

Tags: r

```
code:
mc=aggregate(x= sample_data$length_of_service,
             by = list(sample_data$store_name=="35",sample_data$job_title),
             FUN = mean)[,2:3]
```

```
output :
                        Group.2         x
1                 Accounting Clerk 20.500000
2           Accounts Payable Clerk 19.880000
3       Accounts Receiveable Clerk 19.533333
4                          Auditor 19.150000
5                            Baker  9.927619
6                   Bakery Manager 19.329825
7                   Benefits Admin 19.428571
8                          Cashier  5.491197
9                              CEO 21.500000
10       CHief Information Officer 21.500000
11            Compensation Analyst 19.100000
12                Corporate Lawyer 19.647059
13        Customer Service Manager 19.120915
14                   Dairy Manager 20.000000
15                    Dairy Person  7.435822
16                    Dairy Person 12.109489
17            Director, Accounting 20.888889
18      Director, Accounts Payable 20.888889
19   Director, Accounts Receivable 20.888889
20                 Director, Audit 18.250000
```

I have tried using `sort(mc,decreasing = TRUE)[1:7]` to get the top 7 value but i only receive error message `Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) :  (converted from warning) cannot xtfrm data frames`

What method can i use to extract the top 7 value ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide `sample_data`? You will likely get better help faster that way.

Comment: You need to specify what column to sort, e.g. `sort(mc$x,decreasing = TRUE)[1:7]`

Answer (score 0):

Using base R :

```
head(mc[order(-mc$x),],7)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.